# How to strip GPS location data from an MP4 video file?

Tags: video, privacy, file-metadata

I have a video file captured with a smartphone.
I want to remove the GPS location data written into it, leaving all other information intact. I tried some sed commands, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 12):

You need to remux the video, removing the GPS location metadata.

You can use ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -metadata location="" -metadata location-eng="" -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.mp4
```

Then you can verify with ffprobe:

```
ffprobe output.mp4
```

Comment: This solved my issue with removing gps data from a .mp4 file, I wonder if it's the same process for a MOV file ref: http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php/topic,6037.msg43546.html#msg43546

Comment: Almost worked fine for me with a .mov shot on my iPad. It had HEVC video and AAC audio in it. However, QuickTime Player can't transcode it from HEVC after running `ffmpeg` on it like this.